# Gerar números aleatórios que resultem em uma soma fixa

Tags: javascript, jquery, números-aleatórios, random

Preciso gerar valores aleatórios para os inputs text da minha tabela(lembrando que ela pode ter N linhas), o meu código hoje consegue gerar os números porém preciso que o número gerado seja no máximo X para que não ultrapasse o valor da coluna Máx.

Ex: Se o total for 200, o valor máximo do teste 1 é 150 e do teste 2 é 130, os números devem ser gerados para que o primeiro valor(teste 1) seja no máximo 150 e o segundo(teste 2) no máximo 130 que a soma totalize 200.

Caso a soma dos valores máximos não seja suficiente para chegar no valor digitado, retornar o maior valor possível para cada campo.

Alguém vê uma solução prática para este caso?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alessandroaje/G9U8P/2/)

Comment: São sempre dois valores que devem resultar em um terceiro? Ou você tem N valores cada um com um limite diferente e que a soma deve dar um total fixo?

Comment: Posso ter N linhas/valores @GuilhermeBernal

Comment: Eu não conheço java e não tenho certeza se entendi seu exemplo. Mas acho que esse link vai te ajudar a responder sua pergunta. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5623492

Comment: @MarcosBanik É um ótimo link, talvez você queira colocar como resposta (ainda que não inclua nenhum código JavaScript - já que a dúvida do OP está no algoritmo, não na codificação). Só não sei se vai resolver o problema **todo** - pois as "partições" nesse caso teriam que estar sujeiras a limites superiores.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, ainda não estou seguro para escrever uma resposta. O problema tem 3 parâmetros. Soma, N e max. Se   $Soma <= N * max$ o algoritmo do link resolve o problema. Se $Soma > N * max$ ele pode apelar para um, e apenas um, elemento maior que max. É isso?

Comment: @MarcosBanik Pelo meu entendimento da pergunta, se a soma for maior que os máximos então cada linha deve ficar com o valor máximo e pronto (mesmo que a soma seja inferior à desejada). A dificuldade aqui é que há um máximo diferente **por linha** - e não um `max` global.

Comment: Na verdade aquele algoritmo não resolve nem o caso $Soma <= N * max$, mas ainda acho que dá pra adaptá-lo. Só não dá pra garantir que o primeiro vetor vá resolver o problema.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O algoritmo proposto na minha [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/7090/215) é **funcional** mas não é **justo** (i.e. não distribui o valor de forma uniforme entre as linhas). Se há muitas linhas, as últimas tendem a ficar todas com `0`. Se há poucas, as últimas tendem a ficar com valores muito grandes. Vou propor uma solução alternativa, limitada ao caso em que o número a ser distribuído é **inteiro** e **não excessivamente grande**, baseada na "roleta" dos [algoritmos genéticos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_gen%C3%A9tico):

- De novo, você tem `200` (que chamarei de `alvo`) a serem distribuídos entre N linhas. Para simplificação, dessa vez vamos supor que as linhas não têm mínimos, só máximos (se tiverem, refira-se à primeira parte da minha outra resposta para um meio de se distribuir os mínimos).
- Vamos fazer um loop em que a cada iteração uma das linhas será escolhida e receberá `1` a mais. Ou seja, o loop executará `200` iterações.

  - Primeiro se cria uma "roleta" em que a área de cada linha na roleta é proporcional ao seu valor máximo.
  - Então se sorteia uma linha na roleta; acrescenta-se o valor de `1` e **reduz-se** seu máximo também em `1`. Se ele chegar a zero, a área da roleta destinada a essa linha se tornará zero e ela não mais será sorteada.

Exemplo:

```
var alvo = 200;
var linhas = [{min: 0, max: 150}, {min:0, max: 130}];
var resultado = [0, 0];

function criarRoleta() {
    var ret = [];
    var soma = 0;
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < linhas.length ; i++ ) {
        var valor = linhas[i].max - resultado[i];
        ret.push(valor+soma);
        soma += valor;
    }
    return [ret,soma];
}

for ( var i = 0 ; i < alvo ; i++ ) {
    var roleta = criarRoleta();
    var sorteio = Math.floor(Math.random()*roleta[1]);
    for ( var t = 0 ; t < linhas.length ; t++ )
        if ( sorteio < roleta[0][t] ) {
            resultado[t]++;
            break;
        }
}
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/G9U8P/4/). Note que nesse caso a distribuição tende a ser uniforme, e proporcional ao máximo de cada linha. Distribuições extremas são possíveis, porém raras - o fato de linhas já sorteadas terem suas áreas reduzidas contribui para que as demais linhas aumentem sua chance de serem escolhidas nas rodadas seguintes.

**Atualização:** esse método é equivalente a se abrir uma urna, colocar nela N bolas de cores diferentes (1 para cada espaço disponível em cada linha), e sair removendo bolas ate chegar ao total. Ou seja, a probabilidade de cada linha ser sorteada muda durante o sorteio, de modo que é mais provável que fiquem todas X% cheias do que umas 100% cheias e outras mais vazias.

Se por outro lado o que te interessa é que a chance dos elementos caírem numa linha seja proporcional ao tamanho **inicial** de cada linha, então é necessário "colocar as bolas sorteadas de volta na urna": isso é feito criando-se a roleta uma única vez, em vez de recriá-las a cada iteração (i.e. mova a chamada de `criarRoleta()` para fora do loop). Nesse caso, é preciso verificar a cada sorteio se uma linha chegou ao máximo e - se chegou - "retirar todas as bolas daquela linha da urna" (i.e. atualizar a roleta para que a área daquela linha seja zero, e a soma seja ajustada de acordo).

Comment: Novamente sendo chato: O problema aqui é que a probabilidade de cada campo ser sorteado deve ser proporcional ao seu limite. Se tiver um campo com limite baixo, por exemplo, ele será setado com o valor do limite ou bem próximo (já que o sorteio é uniforme).

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal O sorteio não é uniforme. A área da roleta destinada a cada linha é proporcional ao limite da linha. Como falei, é a mesma técnica usada nos algoritmos genéticos. (a única diferença aqui é que estou **mudando** o limite de forma a favorecer os ainda não sorteados; mas isso pode ser retirado, se conveniente...) P.S. Experimente o fiddle de exemplo colocando os máximos `300` e `30`

Comment: Observe aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/G9U8P/6/. As três soluções possíveis são `88,12`, `89,11` e `90,10`. E todas deveriam ter a mesma probabilidade, mas a primeira acontece bom **muito** mais frequência enquanto que a última quase nunca ocorre.

Comment: "todas deveriam ter a mesma probabilidade" na realidade os requisitos de distribuição não estão bem definidos. Uma medida é a que você propôs ("cada distribuição possível deve ocorrer com a mesma probabilidade"), outra seria ("as linhas devem ter valores uniformes, porém respeitando os limites de cada linha"), e creio que outros requisitos seriam possíveis. Mas concordo que minha solução não satisfaz a seu requisito.

Comment: De fato, o problema não está exatamente claro nesse ponto, e não achei uma forma de gerar uniformemente como mencionei em tempo não exponencial. Então sim, essa é uma boa solução, e uma boa aproximação se os valores dos limites forem próximos (como no exemplo dele).

Comment: @mgibsonbr Essa solução por mais que não tenha a probabilidade proporcional ao seu limite, é justa como você disse e atende a minha necessidade. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Muito obrigado também @GuilhermeBernal pela sua análise!

Answer (score 3):

Creio que você deve abordar o problema por um outro ângulo: você tem na verdade `200` (vou chamar de `alvo`) e quer **distribuir** esse `alvo` por `N` linhas, sendo que cada linha está sujeita a um máximo e talvez a um mínimo. Minha sugestão então é:

- Deduza do seu valor (`alvo`) cada um dos mínimos, e distribua entre as linhas (no seu caso não há mínimos, então o valor continua `200` e cada linha continua com `0`).
- Para cada linha `i` da tabela:

  - Calcule um `minimo = alvo - soma(maximos[i+1:])`; i.e. qual fração desse `alvo` deve **necessariamente** estar nessa linha, pois se não estiver vai ultrapassar os máximos das outras linhas.
  - Sorteie um número entre `minimo` e `min(alvo, maximos[i])`; atribua esse valor à linha e subtraia do `alvo`.

Exemplo:

```
var alvo = 200;
var linhas = [{min: 0, max: 150}, {min:0, max: 130}];
var resultado = [];

// Atribuindo os mínimos
for ( var i = 0 ; i < linhas.length ; i++ ) {
    resultado[i] = linhas[i].min;
    alvo -= linhas[i].min;
}

for ( var i = 0 ; i < linhas.length ; i++ ) {
    // o máximo que pode ser distribuído entre as linhas restantes
    var somaMax = 0;
    for ( var t = i+1 ; t < linhas.length ; t++ )
        somaMax += (linhas[t].max - linhas[t].min);

    // mínimo e máximo para esta linha
    var minimo = alvo < somaMax ? 0 : alvo - somaMax;
    var maximo = Math.min(alvo, linhas[i].max - linhas[i].min);

    // sorteia e atualiza o alvo
    var valor = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maximo-minimo) + minimo);
    resultado[i] += valor;
    alvo -= valor;
}
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/G9U8P/3/).

Comment: Um problema grave aqui é que se o número de linhas for grande, os últimos terão uma forte tendência a serem zeros, ou próximo disso. (estou a ter dificuldade em achar uma forma de fazer isso uniformemente (em tempo aceitável))

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Concordo, o algoritmo proposto aqui não é **justo**. Também não tenho sugestões nesse sentido... :(

Comment: @mgibsonbr Com toda certeza sua sugestão foi ótima e pelo menos consegui abrir a cabeça mais um pouco para resolver o meu problema.

Comment: Muito obrigado também @GuilhermeBernal pela sua analise, essa tendência realmente pode atrapalhar a funcionalidade que busco.

Comment: @AlessandroGomes se essa "parcialidade" for um problema, dê uma olhada na minha [outra resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/7097/215) também. Ela pode ser classificada como "ineficiente", então cabe a você determinar na prática se ela é aplicável ou não (conforme seus valores de entrada).

Answer (score 0):

Vendo no [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) vi que para definir um intervalo para o random e [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) vc precisa usar:

```
Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
```

Sendo assim você pode criar uma função para fazer isso usando os valores de máximo e mínimo como parâmetros assim

```
function randomRange(min, max){
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);
}
```

E usa-la desta forma:

```
randomRange(150,1000);
randomRange($("#inputMinimo").val(),$("#inputMaximo").val());
```

Comment: Como gerar o número com base no valor min e máx eu já sei como funciona, queria saber como aplicar no meu caso de forma prática, mas muito obrigado pela sua resposta.

Comment: Note que isso gera valores **abaixo** do `max`. Esse limite é excludente. (o `min` está incluído)

Comment: No seu segundo código, você não quis dizer `Math.random()*(max-min) + min`? Ex.: pelo seu código, se `min = 10, max = 20`, ele poderia sortear `29` (`19 + 10`).

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.ceil((Math.random()*50)); // Onde 50 é o valor máximo (vai gerar números entre 0 e 50)
```