# Maximizar solução: construção de sublistas atendendo limite

Tags: java, algoritmo, inteligência-artificial

Tendo um conjunto de n-valores, preciso dividir esses itens em subconjuntos que não exceda o valor (soma de todos os itens) estipulado e me garanta que a formação do conjunto é a mais próxima possível do valor estipulado.

Por exemplo, tendo um conjunto de n-itens que o valor total seja de 100D, quero criar listas desses itens que não exceda o valor total de 20D. Nesse caso, o primeiro conjunto deve me oferecer os itens que seus valores seja a melhor solução possível para alcançar os 20D.

Não sei se estou sendo muito confusa, ou prolixa, na minha problemática. Contudo, preciso encaixar performance e atendimento desse requisito nessa solução. Já pesquisei pelo *teorema da mochila* e *Ags* para a solução desse problema, mas acredito haver alguma solução mas simples...

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: A melhor solução possível seria apenas uma combinação mais perto de 20D ou tb importa a quantidade de itens? Tipo, 4 itens que somam 18D é uma solução melhor que 3 itens que somam 18D?

Comment: Não importa a quantidade de itens.. Desculpa Castro. No caso dos 4 para 3. a primeira opção "4 para 18D" é a melhor solução.

Comment: parece muito com essa questão. Te ajuda? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7075/1271

Comment: Marcos, eu não preciso de uma distribuição entre n-listas. Eu preciso que o conjunto do primeiro grupo seja a melhor escolha de itens para se alcançar o valor limite.

Comment: Para se ter uma ideia, eu pensei na seguinte solução: Formar todos os conjuntos possíveis para os elementos - desde que a soma não ultrapasse o valor - e selecionar o grupo que obtiver a maior soma. Porém essa abordagens tem sido muito custosa. Ainda mais porque de início não é possível determinar a quantidade de conjuntos.

Answer (score 2):

Você tem um conjunto de itens e que formar um subconjunto cuja soma seja menor que `X`, de forma que tenha a maior soma possível e que tenha o maior número possível de itens.

Esse problema é bastante similiar ao [**knapsack problem**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_da_mochila):

> [image]
>
> O **problema da mochila** (em inglês, Knapsack problem) é um problema de optimização combinatória. O nome dá-se devido ao modelo de uma situação em que é necessário preencher uma mochila com objetos de diferentes pesos e valores. O objetivo é que se preencha a mochila com o maior valor possível, não ultrapassando o peso máximo.

A diferença é que no seu caso o peso e o valor são a mesma coisa. Você tem um limite de valor, mas você quer maximizar o valor. Esse problema é **NP-Completo**, ou seja: não há solução conhecida para calcular a solução optimal em tempo não exponencial.

Uma solução simples é usar o seguinte algoritmo recursivo:

```ruby
# Encontre o maior conjunto com os n primeiros itens de set tal que seja menor que o limit
def bestsubset(set, n, limit)
    if n == 0
        # O melhor conjunto com zero itens é o conjunto vazio
        return []
    end

    if set[n-1] > limit
        # Se o ultimo for menor que o limite, exclua ele
        return bestsubset(set, n-1, limit)
    end

    # a = melhor conjunto excluindo o ultimo item
    # b = melhor conjunto incluindo o ultimo item
    a = bestsubset(set, n-1, limit)
    b = bestsubset(set, n-1, limit-set[n-1]) + [set[n-1]]

    # computar as somas
    sum_a = a.reduce(:+) || 0
    sum_b = b.reduce(:+) || 0

    if sum_a > sum_b
        return a
    else
        # se soma deu igual, retorna o que tem mais itens
        return b
    end
end
```

.

```ruby
p bestsubset([3,1,1,1,2,7], 6, 5)  #=> [1, 1, 1, 2]
```

Escrevi em ruby, mas você pode adaptar para qualquer linguagem.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o que você procura é isto:

http://marathoncode.blogspot.com.br/2012/09/algoritmo-de-kadane.html

Caso você queira um conjunto de valor exato a 20D, você deve pesquisar sobre SubSet Sum.

Comment: Pelo que vi do link, ele maximiza a soma, mas não impõe um limite.

Comment: Verdade, não tinha interpretado direito a pergunta.